# Showing equation for credit spread

Tags: finance

Question:
Show that in general, we have s ≈ q × LGD.
Where s= credit spread, q= one year risk neutral probability, and LGD is the loss given default.

Answer (score 1):

1 year default probability $= q$

credit spread $= s$

LGD $= l$

t year cumulative default probability $$= 1-e^{-\frac{ts}{l}} = q$$
$1-q = e^{-\frac{ts}{l}}$

Taking natural logarithm on both sides and t = 1, we get

$ln(1-q) = -\frac{s}{l}$

$s = -ln(1-q)\times l$

$s\approx q\times l $= Default probability $\times$ Loss Given Default

Then the question is how do you get the first formula it comes from survival probability.